# Convert BSON to valid JSON

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

The `BsonDocument.ToJson()` method returns invalid JSON, as `ObjectID()` and `ISODate` are not valid JSON.

What's the best way to get valid JSON from an arbitary BSON document?

Comment: I find it odd that ["strict" mode](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) is not the default, but that is the case. At a guess I'd say more users voted for being able to "cut/paste" output directly into the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var document = new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId());
    var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict }; // key part
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings));
```

For More info 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/fQc9EvsPc4k

Comment: I did this, but, when I return this json in api, I get all the trailing \ inside the json. How to manage that?

Comment: Now instead of `"Property" : NumberDecimal("23.44")` i get `"Property" : {  "$numberDecimal": "23.44"} ` - Can't it just put the decimal value in the result like a normal person? I just want `"Property" : 23.44`

Comment: @Kula change OutPutMode to `JsonOutputMode.RelaxedExtendedJson`